# Merge [little-endian], [big-endian], and [byte-order] into [endianness]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Should the [little-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/little-endian), [big-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-endian), and [byte-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/byte-order) tags become synonyms of the [endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endianness) tag?

You must have at least five points in the [endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endianness) tag and be able to correctly determine the endianness of the byte 01100110 to weigh in.

**Vote for synonyms here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/endianness/synonyms**

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Dunno.  You can be an expert in endianness, but I don't think anybody is only an expert in one type and not the other.  That suggests little/big-endian tags are meta tags.  However, they do distinguish the type of problem you're having, so may result in better answers coming your way.  I'm split between the two.

Comment: A lot of questions tagged [tag:little-endian] or [tag:big-endian] are tagged *both*.

Comment: @Will: How do they distinguish the type of problem?  There's only one problem, which is **endianness-mismatch**.  Neither are they meta tags, because they do describe the question technical content, not its metadata (who wrote the question, how much do they know -- these are the questions meta tags answer)

Comment: @BenVoigt I dunno, I'm not an endian expert :)

Comment: 01100110 is one of the most endian-neutral values (`11111111` is even more neutral)

Comment: The synonyms are [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/endianness/synonyms) — now you need to get some other people to up-vote them.  Should [tag:byte-order] be included in this synonym ring?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, [tag:byte-order] should be included, definitely.

Comment: I know a lot about big endian systems and little about little endian systems.  However, I do think byte-order would be the best canonical tag.

Comment: @WarrenDew: I agree with that assessment — I think [tag:byte-order] should be the canonical tag for all three 'endian' tags.  With that said, it only has 99 questions at the moment.  If the little-endian and big-endian tags become synonyms of endianness, and then endianness is made into a synonym of byte-order, I think (assume? or does that make …) that they all end up as one tag, don't they.

Comment: endian little into merged be should they think I.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Endianness can also mean bit order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with Ben that endianness should be the canonical tag.

Comment: I'm OK with making [tag:byte-order] a synonym of [tag:endianness].  So much so that I've proposed that synonym too.  Now to get a few more people who can vote to agree...at least this question has been featured on 'Hot Meta Posts'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Votes cast, unfortunately, we lost the hotness.  I'll edit my answer to make the need for votes clearer, though, and that will also bump this.

Answer (score 31):

[endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endianness) is the concept, big-endian and little-endian are just enumerating implementations.

We don't need separate tags for all the natural numbers (Tags for zero, one, and forty-two, anyone?) and neither do we need tags for the different enumerated endiannesses, since they all do exactly the same thing -- map between address (if parallel) or timing (if serial transfer) and place value.

Synonymize them to [endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endianness) by voting [here (if you have a badge in the tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/endianness/synonyms).

Comment: There are [557 questions tagged `zero`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) - but not one with `one`. (I didn't check beyond that.)

Comment: @Jongware: It appears that you found 557 users in need of a proper tutorial on tagging.

Comment: Looking at the titles, I bet most of them will defend themselves with "but it was suggested by the system!" I briefly glanced over it and saw exactly *zero* instances where the tag added something useful.

Comment: @Jongware: In addition to blacklisted tags, we need a list of 1-Delta-10-Tango tags, that don't allow the user back onto the main site until they spend some time in the FAQs.

Comment: @Jongware: Well, that's why they tagged them `zero`, of course! :P

Comment: The trouble with the tag forty-two is that it only belongs on the answers, not the questions, and it belongs on all the useful answers.  (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29) if you're not sure what I mean...)

Comment: @Jonathan: But all questions want useful answers, so it does belong on the questions.  Along with [tag:thanks-for-all-the-fish].